# Mile stones in my EB1-B Green Card application

Tags: usa, visa, greencard, h1-visa, employment

I recently left a company sponsoring my Green Card through EB1-b. Now my question is regarding the Green Card application and the next mile stones. The process was taken care of through a law firm partnering with my company. My receipts have SRCxxx number, meaning it is processed in Texas Center. I'm living in Texas myself.

- In July/August 2017, my I-140 was approved (I was under OPT that time).
- We then submitted the I-485, I-485J (bona fide job offer), and I-765 in October 18, 2017 (that time I was in my H1B- Looks like my status was switched from OPT to H1B around same time). Around 150 days have been passed till now.
- I did biometrics in Nov. 13, 2017
- My case was transferred to NBC center on Dec 27, 2017
- I got an RFE in Jan 29 (lawyers forgot my Birth Certificate!), and it was taken care of.
- I got my EAD/AP approved in Feb 7, and received in 14 Feb (C09 category).

I talked to the law firm, and they said it is their common practice not to withdraw the I-140.

Now what is the next mile-stone? With the current queue, when should I expect to receive my GC? Now that I don't have a job, does it affect my GC (how uscis knows I don't have a job?!)

Comment: I know that people from some countries can wait for their employer-sponsored green cards much longer than others. There are separate queues, I think.